# Harmonic partitions of 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, harmonic-numbers

I was trying to find finite partitions of integer inverses that would add up to one, after a few experiments I struck upon this beautiful partition:

$$ 1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{2 × 3 × 7} $$

I tried to determine if there was a general rule to finding more such partitions adding more terms but the problem quickly gets unwieldly

Is there a general principle for obtaining this family of partitions? The numerand on the first set of elements seems to be a [permanent](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)) of the partition elements, and the Diophantic condition for said partitions seems to be that the permanent must be one less than the product of all the elements

$$ perm(a_0,a_1 \dots, a_n) = ( \prod_i a_i) - 1$$

But of course this only applies on this "special" family, I haven't been able to figure out if there can be partitions of 1 that don't abide to this amusing pattern

NB: The terminology of the title is accurate to best of my knowledge, which isn't much, so please correct me if it's the case

Comment: See the [Sylvester sequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want $\sum_{k\in S} \frac{1}{k} = 1$, then note that for any unit fraction we have $\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{k + 1} + \frac{1}{k(k + 1)}$. Your example is a special case of this:

$$
1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6}\right) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{42}
$$

In particular, you can define a sequence where $a_1 = 2$ and $a_{n + 1} = 1 + \prod_{k=1}^n a_k$. Then, $\frac{1}{a_N - 1} + \sum_{k=1}^{N - 1} \frac{1}{a_k} = 1$ for all $N$.

Verification code on [tio.run](https://tio.run/##TY5BDsIgEEXXcopZQqzG6s7ErUsu0DRm0lIlLQOhsPD0CNaq2//m/T/uGR6WTikN3hoYPHZBW5pBG2d9gOsnYAuO1AVrpy/2qo@dWqB1ymOwfmUmTowhwQWaY8uGDG6gCTzSXfH6IM5sg7RH5xT1fCni2akAScAWasHekvxJkyKeYTGd1xS4rGCOhq9P8rqCUUCxxmIhNWfZlrL/i5zKFnZ5QKT0Ag).

---

Another interesting class of solutions can be obtained from perfect numbers. Take $N = 2^{k-1}(2^k-1)$ where $2^k - 1$ is a prime. We know that this is a perfect number. Now consider its divisors $S = \{d \in \mathbb{N} : d \mid N\}$. Summing the reciprocal of divisors, we have

$$
\sum_{d \in S} \frac{1}{d} = \sum_{d} \frac{1}{d} = \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{k - 1}}\right)\left(1 + \frac{1}{2^k - 1}\right) = 2
$$

Subtracting the $1$ gives another unit fraction decomposition of $1$, say $1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{14} + \frac{1}{28}$.

Comment: I keep looking at the reasoning, look at the expression, look back at the reasoning, and if this isn't magic, then nothing can be magic

Comment: @lurscher If you mean the part where I wrote $\sum_d \frac{1}{d} = \left(\cdot\right)\left(\cdot\right)$, that's the euler product since $\frac{1}{d}$ is (completely) multiplicative. Try writing the product out for $k = 3$ i.e. $N = 2^2\cdot 7$ if it's not clear.

Comment: I don't meant that, I just mean that these partitions were utterly unexpected to me, and on the light of the commenter that mentioned the Sylvester sequence, I cannot help but shout in awe out all this sorcery

Comment: I haven't checked but it seems that the Sylvester sequence generates a small subset of these partititions, and for large numbers they become mostly irrelevant

Comment: Yea it's a pretty cool idea stemming from an elementary partial fraction decomposition. You can definitely explore this idea further though; For example, you can first write $1 = \frac{1}{k} \cdot k$, then expanding each fraction until you don't get any duplicate. What's the final length? What do the sequences look like? In this sense, the Sylvester sequence is kind of "1-dimensional"/linear, but you can definitely make it more complex into a tree-like shape :)